# Does BoundedCapacity include items currently being processed in TPL Dataflow?

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library, tpl-dataflow

Does the `BoundedCapacity` limit only includes items in the input queue waiting to be processed or does it also count items being processed at the moment?

Lets take for example this `ActionBlock`:

```
var block = new ActionBlock<int>(
    i => Console.WriteLine(i),
    new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions
    {
        BoundedCapacity = 1000,
        MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 10,
    });
```

If there are currently 5 items being processed in parallel. Does that mean the input queue can hold 1000 items more **on top** of these, or just 995?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Evidently, `BoundedCapacity` indeed includes the items being processed on top of the items waiting in the input queue. This can be easily demonstrated with an `ActionBlock` that has the same `ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions` with an `action` that never finishes:

```
var block = new ActionBlock<int>(
    _ => Task.Delay(-1),
    new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions
    {
        BoundedCapacity = 1000,
        MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 10,
    });

for (int i = 0; i < 1001; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("#{0} - InputCount={1}", i, block.InputCount);
    await block.SendAsync(i);
}
```

The output would be as follows and then the application would block indefinitely:

```
...
...
#990 - InputCount=980
#991 - InputCount=981
#992 - InputCount=982
#993 - InputCount=983
#994 - InputCount=984
#995 - InputCount=985
#996 - InputCount=986
#997 - InputCount=987
#998 - InputCount=988
#999 - InputCount=989
#1000 - InputCount=990
```

That's because 1000 items were added, 10 of them (`MaxDegreeOfParallelism`) are being processed concurrently, the other 990 are waiting in the input queue and the 1001<sup>st</sup> item could never get in.

Comment: So BoundedCapacity is an upper bound for the max DOP as well.

Comment: @usr Exactly. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26577051/885318) is how I got to this question.